# Cannot resolve in X

Tags: networking, midori, web-browsers

When I am in the terminal command-line, domain name resolution works fine.
However, when I start X then Midori cannot resolve domain names, nor can I resolve them in a terminal emulator.

Any ideas on fixing?

An interesting article at https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/29

Comment: @AlexChamberlain: no as I mentioned in the question

Comment: Can you ping a static IP? (i.e. do you lose the network entirely?) Anything in dmesg? Does getting out of X fix it again?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be my USB hub. I'm not sure why problem only occurs in X. Perhaps mouse is the real culprit.

Comment: I've seen similar things. There is probably more traffic with different drivers active. Maybe the device power load also increases.